# Which system's mechanical energy is conserved?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, energy-conservation

As the figure shows, $m$ starts falling down from its current position at the original speed of zero. And $M$ is a curved side trapezoid. All friction can be ignored.

> |# <- This hash stands for $m$
>
> |.\
>
> |....\
>
> |.......\
>
> |....$M$....\        <— Imagine this surface is curved
>
> |...................\
>
> |________________\
>
> ---
>
> ↑ Don't forget the ground is smooth

(It seems that some problems occur in my network connection, so I'm not able to upload a picture for you for the time being. Sorry about that!)

My question is: The mechanical energy of which system is conserved in the progress? The one formed by $m$ and $M$, or the one formed by $m$, $M$ and the Earth?

I'm new to this site and my English is not good. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: A picture would really help, but let me confirm: $m$ starts sliding down a ramp $M$ sitting on the ground, and there's no friction, so $M$ starts sliding to the left as its surface accelerates $m$ to the right. And you're wondering what energy is conserved?

Comment: @DanielGriscom The part about the accelerating process is right, but what actually confused me is what `mechanical energy of a system` stands for.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Mass, no friction.]

> All friction can be ignored.

In that case Conservation of Energy applies:

$$U+K=mgh$$

So that when the mass reaches the bottom of the ramp:

$$K=\frac{mv^2}{2}=mgh$$

> My question is: The mechanical energy of which system is conserved in the progress? The one formed by m and M, or the one formed by m, M and the Earth?

The system here is mass, ramp and the Earth.

Comment: The OP has recently clarified that in his problem the ramp moves as well, sliding along the ground. But, since the OP seems to have accepted your answer, perhaps we're all confused...

Comment: @DanielGriscom Sorry, I'm new to this site, so I don't know the rules quite well. This answer was accepted due to its last sentense.